# Can virtfs/9p be used to share the same host folder with multiple guests?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, virtfs

So far I have resorted to sharing host folders with the KVM guests via Samba. Now, reading up a bit on it, it appears that ["VirtFS (Plan 9 folder sharing over Virtio - I/O virtualization framework)"](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup) offers an easier way.

However, I was unable to find on above linked page whether this method allows concurrent access to the same shared folder for multiple KVM guests.

Answer (score 3):

Main goal of 9p filesystem is to provide easy and efficient way to share filesystems between host/guest and guests (compared to nfs and shared block devices).

By default no cache used in linux implementation of 9p filesystem (read [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/9p.txt)), so it can be used to share same filesystem between guests.